# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is taking forever to update environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have battled with deploying my app on elastic beanstalk and rds for over two days now and just when i figured out the issue, elastic beanstalk is taking over 10 hours now still updating environment . I stopped the action earlier on and restart again. It's still running for over 5 hours . This started yesterday.Before it takes roughly 5 min or less to update my environment. The update were trigger after i added my rds host , user and passwords etc.

I am running **Instance type: t1.micro** , **Proxy server: nginx**, **Node version: 4.4.3**.

Please have anyone else encounter this issue before? How do i addressed it ?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by Rebuilding the environment, before that I saved my configuration.

Good Luck